# What is the appropriate way to request a creator to add more of their designs to MOCHUB?

Tags: technic, creator

There are some brilliant LEGO creators with many designs on YouTube out there who choose to remain anonymous- who put some of their designs on MOCHUB but not others. (In particular ones relating to pneumatic engines.)

There might be a reason for this I’m missing.

I could comment on YouTube but then my comment would be against my name for all to see forever, and I’d prefer a communication method more discreet.

What is the appropriate way to request a creator to add more of their designs to MOCHUB?

Comment: I see LEGO fans asking the question all the time if the creator would share instructions (via LDD, MOCHub, ReBrick, etc.). There is no shame in asking the question. The worst that can happen is they say no. Many LEGO fans don't care for sharing instructions because they build models on the fly and don't want to spend the time re-creating them digitally, or they don't want to have someone steal their designs. I just don't see why you would be so concerned that others can see you asking a simple question that many others ask. You can also send them a private message via YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some creators may not want to share building instructions as there is a fear of knock-off companies releasing them as sets. Especially if MOC's are of top quality.

It is also possible there a personal choice to limit (control) their work results via fewer platforms. Or simply may not like some platforms at all.

Edit: Thinking from my point of view (someone who has created and shared instructions for LEGO MOC) I would consider alternative web redources if there would be obvious benefits. So it might be worth finding such reasons, like audience growth, unique features, something else. Then contact the author via one of the ways he is available and suggest him to contribute to your choice of web portal listing the possible reasons. It could be the easiest way of letting this person know and understand if he has anything against it.

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  While you've explained the designer's motivations well, it doesn't seem like this actually answers the question.  Can you add a bit more to this to tie it together?